# listoffigures not working properly

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I have noticed that in my document the `\listoffigures` and probaly `\listoftables` are not working properly. There is no space in between the number of the figure and the text in the list. Also, if the figure number has more than 1 digit after dot, it is then overplapping with the text. Here is a screen:

[image: list of figures]

Here is my test code to reproduce the problem:

```
%% Clear sans, courier

% Klasa:
\documentclass[12pt]{mwart}

% Kodowanie:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Czcionki:
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Clear Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Geometria i style
%\usepackage{showframe} % debug
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,inner=35mm,outer=20mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Grafika
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

% kody
\usepackage{listings}

% matma
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% theoremy
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Stopnie
\usepackage{gensymb}

% Numerowanie obiektow wedlug rozdzialow
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Linki
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyref}

% Listy
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

% Zmienne srodowiskowe:
\newcommand{\tocLessLeft}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessLeftNorm}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\normalsize \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{0mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessCenter}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \centerline{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\insertImg}[3]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm]{#1}
    \caption{#2} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#3}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\insertImgSetSize}[4]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2mm]{#1}
    \caption{#3} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#4}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}

% Indeksowanie w pdfie wyjsciowym
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Naprawienie referencji do figur
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.section.thesection.\thefigure}

% START:
\begin{document}

\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

I dont know how to fix this listing and I would appreciate all help in resolving the problem. If any other information are needed I can add them.

Comment: You are aware that we can't compile this? We don't have the image, so use the `[demo]` option for `graphicx`.

Comment: Sorry, I will remember this for the next time. Thank you for the answer bellow it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `numwidth` for figures is too small (which seems the fault of the `mwart` class.)

Either redefine `\l@figure` or use

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{10pt}
```

to add more space, say, `10pt`, here. Choose another value at will.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{mwart}

% Kodowanie:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{10pt}

% Czcionki:
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Clear Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
\usepackage{courier}

% Geometria i style
%\usepackage{showframe} % debug
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,inner=35mm,outer=20mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Grafika
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

% kody
\usepackage{listings}

% matma
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% theoremy
%\usepackage{amsthm}

% Stopnie
\usepackage{gensymb}

% Numerowanie obiektow wedlug rozdzialow
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Linki
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyref}

% Listy
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

% Zmienne srodowiskowe:
\newcommand{\tocLessLeft}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessLeftNorm}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\normalsize \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{0mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessCenter}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \centerline{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\insertImg}[3]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm]{#1}
    \caption{#2} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#3}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\insertImgSetSize}[4]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2mm]{#1}
    \caption{#3} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#4}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}

% Indeksowanie w pdfie wyjsciowym
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Naprawienie referencji do figur
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.section.thesection.\thefigure}

% START:
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}
\insertImg{stepper_nema17.png}{text}{fake_cite}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before anybody complains: I solved the main issue, not other things here!